# Where is StackOverflow bugzilla or other bugtracker?

Tags: support, bug-reporting-process

I want to report StackOverflow bug (e.g. problem with security) in place  where developers and product managers see it and can react (change SO code or something) - where I can do it? If such system exists provide link

Comment: If you have found a security issue please follow the guidance given [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/security).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (or [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) are the best place to report bugs. Just tag them with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug). If you found something that should not be discussed in the open (critical security bugs or privacy stuff), you can also use the "Contact Us" link on the bottom of each page

Comment: Meta.SO don't looks like bug tracker - because there is no TRACKING there - for example where are bug statuses (like e.g  'resoved', 'closed' etc.)? What about bug history and dependece? Where is info about bug importance/priority? Where are the info which developer(s) fix the bug?  How I can know that reported bug was read by person who can decide to fix it or not? What about email info (or SO message) to person who report bug when is fixed to give him chance to TEST solution (and give feedback)? Here is bug [tacker for firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361876) as example

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski we have [meta-tag:status-completed] and other status tags on all of our meta sites. :) If it's a bug in our security that you don't want to make public, you can use the contact form. Our meta sites have long been our way of responding to bugs on our sites.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski: Stack Overflow is not an open source project, so there's no need for an explicit bug tracking and resolution system on that score; nor does it contain executable code or other binary resources that a programmer would take a dependency on, so there's no need for one on that score, either.

Comment: If the bug is related to a security issue it should not be posted on Meta, it should be reported directly to SO via email. See [How do I report a possible security vulnerability?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/security-reports) in the Help Center.